# AppleScript hangs when mounting notremovable encrypted image

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to mount a dmg as nonremovable image using AppleScript as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/340312/359326).
The difference is that my dmg is encrypted.

When I execute

```
do shell script "hdiutil attach /path/to/my.dmg -notremovable" with administrator privilege
```

root password is asked and then nothing happens (I'd expect a prompt for dmg's password) and the script runs until closed in Activity Monitor.

If the script is executed without `"with administrator privilege"` then the dmg's password is asked right before I get "hdiutil: attach failed - Permission denied" error.

The console version works fine:

```
sudo hdiutil attach /path/to/my.dmg -notremovable
```

Why AppleScript does not ask for the dmg's password? Does it "hide" the second prompt for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know how to do in properly, but here is the workaround:

```
display dialog "Password for the image" default answer "" with hidden answer
set the pass to the text returned of the result

do shell script "echo -n " & pass & " | hdiutil attach /path/to.dmg -notremovable -stdinpass" with administrator privileges
```